# Passing more than one object to an EJB remote interface

Tags: rmi, glassfish-3, ejb-3.1

I am trying to pass more than object to an EJB remote interface deployed no Glassfish 3.1.1. Whatever is the first object it will pass fine the second object is always null. Is it due to the specs of rmi-iiop or is it a property setting?

Here is my property settings:

```
final Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty(InitialContext.STATE_FACTORIES,
            "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
    props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs",
            "com.sun.enterprise.naming");
    props.setProperty("java.naming.factory.state",
            "com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl");
        props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "192.168.1.192");
        props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
    // props.setProperty("com.sun.appserv.iiop.orbconnections","5");
    // Increase ORB Response Timeout to 5 min instead of 30 min:
    // props.setProperty("com.sun.corba.ee.transport.ORBTCPTimeouts",
    // "500:90000:20");
    props.setProperty(
            "com.sun.corba.ee.transport.ORBWaitForResponseTimeout",
            "300000");
    try {
        InitialContext ic=new InitialContext(props);
        TestRemote remote=(TestRemote) ic.lookup("java:global/com.capmtech_test.ear-ear_ear_1.0-SNAPSHOT/test.ear-ejb-1.0-SNAPSHOT/Test!com.capmtech.TestRemote");


                    Person p = new Person();
                    p.setName("Smith");
                    Phone m = new Phone();

            remote.test(p, m);

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Here is the stateless EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class Test implements TestRemote {
    @EJB
    private PersonFacadeLocal personFacade;

    @Override
    public void test(Person person, Phone mobile) {
        Person p = person;
        p.setMobile(mobile);
        personFacade.create(p);
    }

    // Add business logic below. (Right-click in editor and choose
    // "Insert Code > Add Business Method")

}
```

In this case mobile will always be null, if I swap the aruguments person would be null! If the IP was set to localhost everything would work fine.

Please help

Comment: What do you mean by "pass more than one object"?  Do you mean you have a method with two parameters on a remote interface, and your first argument is fine but the second argument is null?  That seems very strange.

Comment: I see you're setting a lot of properties to get it working.  According to the [documentation](http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/ejb/EJB_FAQ.html), you should be using the no-args InitialContext().  It is very strange that the behavior changes when you set the ip address.  Maybe you've got problems with the way /etc/hosts is set up, or with a firewall?  Glassfish is [picky](http://www.iniy.org/?p=275) about the /etc/hosts config.

Comment: That seems quite strange.  I've never seen this behavior.  I suppose I would recommend creating a standalone testcase and opening a bug report with Glassfish.

Answer (score 0):

replace the following lines:

```
    props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "192.168.1.192");
    props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
```

with:

```
    props.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"iiop://192.168.1.192:3700");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all assuming you are running your glassfish server and the standalone client on the same machine.  I am able to reproduce a problem in this area.  While it is not exactly your problem, you may get results with the same changes.  I am running GF 3.1 on Windows Vista.  My windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts file has the following lines:

```
10.99.0.199 pc-2017.pgx.local
127.0.0.1       localhost  pc-2017.pgx.local
```

When my client software connects with:

```
props.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
```

I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.RemoteException: CORBA INTERNAL 1330446421 No; nested exception is:
    org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.INTERNAL: WARNING: IOP00710085: A reflective tie got an error while invoking method saveMonkey on class com.pts.monkey._MonkeySessionRemote_Remote
  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 85  completed: No
```

but then if I change the client to connect with:

```
props.put("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "pc-2017.pgx.local");
```

it works correctly.